# Elasticsearch rolling upgrade - do deleted documents get removed?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm going to upgrade Elasticsearch from 5.6 to 6.8 following the [rolling upgrade procedure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/rolling-upgrades.html).

I have an index which is 54,172,622 documents across 5 primary shards, with 1 replica of each. There are 21,696,332 deleted documents in the index.

When I follow the rolling upgrade procedure, will the procedure automatically purge the deleted documents, or is it better to reindex to a new index before upgrading? I assume the upgrade is slower if the deleted documents are included.

Answer (score 1):

> When I follow the rolling upgrade procedure, will the procedure automatically purge the deleted documents

No, upgrading will *NOT* modify your `docs.count` or `docs.deleted`. The counts will remain the same.

> is it better to reindex to a new index before upgrading?

Just because you want to upgrade doesn't mean you need to re-index. It depends. If your index was created in versions prior to 5.x, then you *might* need to upgrade. The best way to determine this is to run the `Upgrade Assistant` tool in Kibana. You'll need to `reindex` some internal indices like `.kibana`, `.security`, `.tasks`, `.watches` and the Upgrade Assistant will help to reindex those indices. It will also tell you if your main index containing `54,172,622` docs needs to be re-indexed or not. Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/6.8/upgrading-elastic-stack.html

> I assume the upgrade is slower if the deleted documents are included.

I don't think the value of `docs.deleted` impacts the upgrade process. It's just a count.